# How do I detect if a single JRadioButton is selected or not using ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing

First, Here is the code in its entirety. It was mostly auto generated by netbeans as i am terrible at creating GUIs:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package multisearch;

 /**
  *
  * @author ikill
*/
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form GUI
 */
public GUI() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    jFormattedTextField3 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jFormattedTextField4 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("First Name:");

    jTextField1.setColumns(15);

    jLabel2.setText("Last Name:");

    jTextField2.setColumns(15);

    jLabel3.setText("Age:");

    jButton1.setText("Search");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel4.setText("Start Date:");

    jLabel5.setText("End Date:");

    jFormattedTextField1.setColumns(10);
    jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))));

    jFormattedTextField2.setColumns(10);
    jFormattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))));

    jFormattedTextField3.setColumns(3);
    jFormattedTextField3.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));

    jRadioButton1.setText("Search by age");
    jRadioButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel6.setText("Number of concurrent searches:");

    jFormattedTextField4.setColumns(3);
    jFormattedTextField4.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(jFormattedTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(jFormattedTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jRadioButton1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    javax.swing.JRadioButton tempBtn = (javax.swing.JRadioButton) evt.getSource();
    if (tempBtn.isEnabled()) {
        jFormattedTextField1.enableInputMethods(false);
        jFormattedTextField2.enableInputMethods(false);
        System.out.println("Date box disabled");
    }

}                                             

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField2;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField3;
private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JRadioButton jRadioButton1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Here is where I am having trouble:

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(jRadioButton1.isEnabled()) {
        jFormattedTextField1.enableInputMethods(false);
        jFormattedTextField2.enableInputMethods(false);
        System.out.println("Date box disabled!");
    }

}
```

I've tried using:

```
private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    javax.swing.JRadioButton tempBtn = (javax.swing.JRadioButton)evt.getSource();
    if(tempBtn.isEnabled()) {
        jFormattedTextField1.enableInputMethods(false);
        jFormattedTextField2.enableInputMethods(false);
        System.out.println("Date box disabled");
```

In an attempt to check if the button is ticked or not. 
However, each time I tick or untick the button, it prints "Date box disabled!", in both methods, despite there being a check if the button is enabled. 
Here is a screengrab of the GUI:
[Picture of the GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0z3z.png)

My end goal is for the Start date and end date text fields to be disabled when the Search by age button is ticked, and for the Age text field to be disabled when the radio button is unticked.
I'm not sure if the method I'm checking the buttons status is incorrect, or if there is something else wrong with my code :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want `isSelected`, not `isEnabled`

Comment: You may find [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and the [JavaDocs for `JRadioButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) of some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally to enabling/disabling certain buttons based on a button's state, you should not use a JRadioButton instance, we need to have JCheckBox in that place to cater the needs.

I modified the code with JCheckBox and enabling/disabling buttons based on check box state with help of ItemListener and ItemEvent. ItemEvent has one useful method getStateChange() which will returns you about whether checkbox is Selected or Deselected. Based on that you can do your required operations.

To enable/disable a particular component user setEnabled(boolean value) method.
Pass value as true if you want to enable, false otherwise.

Here is the short code jcheckbox listener code :

```
checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            boolean flag = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
            jFormattedTextField1.setEnabled(!flag);// Here if check box is selected then flag value will be true and this text field would be disabled
            jFormattedTextField2.setEnabled(!flag);
            jFormattedTextField3.setEnabled(flag);
        }
    });
```

And below is the entire working code.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package multisearch;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

/**
 *
 * @author ikill
 */
public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form GUI
     */
    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jFormattedTextField2 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        jFormattedTextField3 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        checkBox = new JCheckBox();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jFormattedTextField4 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("First Name:");

        jTextField1.setColumns(15);

        jLabel2.setText("Last Name:");

        jTextField2.setColumns(15);

        jLabel3.setText("Age:");

        jButton1.setText("Search");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setText("Start Date:");

        jLabel5.setText("End Date:");

        jFormattedTextField1.setColumns(10);
        jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))));

        jFormattedTextField2.setColumns(10);
        jFormattedTextField2.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"))));

        jFormattedTextField3.setColumns(3);
        jFormattedTextField3.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));

        checkBox.setText("Search by age");
        checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                boolean flag = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
                jFormattedTextField1.setEnabled(!flag);
                jFormattedTextField2.setEnabled(!flag);
                jFormattedTextField3.setEnabled(flag);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setText("Number of concurrent searches:");

        jFormattedTextField4.setColumns(3);
        jFormattedTextField4.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter(java.text.NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                                        .addComponent(jLabel5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                                                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(checkBox)
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                                .addComponent(jFormattedTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addContainerGap()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                        .addComponent(jFormattedTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(checkBox)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(jButton1)
                                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox checkBox;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration
    }
```

Still if you want to do with JRadioButton, you can use itemListener as I have used above.

Comment: Thanks for this, might i ask why itemListener should be used over ActionListener?

Comment: If you use Action Listener, you will get action event fired when check box got checked or unchecked but with the ActionEvent object it's not possible to find out what the action is - means whether the action is checked action or unchecked action. However Item Listener is providing ItemEvent with capability of letting the interested party know whether check box got selected or not with the help of getStateChange() method. getStateChange() returns ITEMEVENT.SELECTED when check box selected and returns ITEMEVENT.DESELECTED when check box got unchecked